# Which html5 element would be best used in the footer for a copyright and/or site name

Tags: html

Prior to HTML5, I always used `<h1>` for the title of my page. Then used subsequent `<h2> <h3> <h4>`... for the rest of my page.

With HTML5, I've read that I can use `<h1>` multiple times in a document. Such uses would be for a blog with multiple posts and using the element for the blog title.

However, I never found which element is best used for the footer of a document. Let's say you want to put a copyright with the name of your website. Would you use `<h1> <div> <p>` for the layout below?

```
                                                         Copyright 2015 My Web Site Title
```

ie:

```
 <footer>
   <h1>Copyright....</h1>
 </footer>
```

Comment: you question's title seem ask a different question than its closing question.  Is this about `h1` tags in general or specifically in the footer?

Comment: Specifically in the footer. I will reword it.

Answer (score 1):

For the footer of your document, use `<footer>`

Comment: I do, but which markup would work best for putting a copyright or web site title like I illustrated above?

Comment: Well, all the <h..> are for headings right, and the copyright stuff isn't a heading, it's just normal text, so I assume it would make the most sense to use the paragraph tags <p>

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, you can use`<h1>` tags multiple times in the same document as long as each has a separate `<article>` parent, denoting each `article`'s primary `h`eading

```
<article>
 <h1> this article </h1>
</article>

<article>
 <h1> that article </h1>
</article>

<article>
 <h1> some other article </h1>
</article>
```

inside a `footer`, there's no reason I can think of to add a `h`eading. This should all be sufficient:

```
<footer>
  <div> short line here </div>
  <ul> 
   <li><a href="..........  link to something
   <li><a href="..........  link to something
   <li><a href="..........  link to something
  </ul>
  <p> significat parting message, thatnks for using our site, we would
      like to hear from you again </p>
</footer>
```

> **side-note**: stack overflow uses `div`s for almost everything in their footer
>
> ```
> <div id="copyright">
>   site design / logo &copy; 2015 Stack Exchange Inc; 
>   user contributions licensed under 
>   <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">cc by-sa 3.0</a>
>   with <a rel="license" href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/">
>     attribution required
>   </a>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: So would you recommend using `<p>` or `<div>` ?